# How to filter stream values using Map of Lists?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a list of entities and I need to remove some of them using filter and Map with necessary keys and values.

It looks like that. There is a `List<Comment> commentsList` and `Map<Integer, List<Post>> postsById`. Comment entity has method `getByPostId`. Map looks like `<Post id, has amount of comments>`.
I need to remove from `commentsList` comments that are related to Post that has less than 3 comments.
I tried to do like that:

```
Stream<E> ofAtLeastComments(Stream<E> comments, Stream<Post> posts, Integer count) {
    Map<Integer, List<Post>> postById = posts
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Post::getId)
            );
    return comments
            .filter(comment -> postById.get(comment.getCommentId()).size() >= count);
}
```

But it return zero value.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your map keys are the post IDs, not the comment IDs.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing and doesn't give enough information about exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @Alexey, please ✓ an answer or update your question.

Answer (score 0):

As JB Nizet pointed out, the code seems to confuse post ids and comment ids:

```
Stream<E> ofAtLeastComments(Stream<E> comments, Stream<Post> posts, Integer count) {
    Map<Integer, List<Post>> posts = posts.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Post::getId));
    return comments.filter(comment -> posts.get(comment.getPostId()).size() >= count);
    //                                                     ^^^^
}
```

But the method name sounds more like you want this:

```
<E extends Comment> Stream<Post> ofAtLeastComments(Stream<E> comments, Stream<Post> posts, Integer count) {
    // Number of comments per post ID 
    Map<Integer, Long> commentCounts = comments
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Comment::getPostId, Collectors.counting()));
    return posts.filter(post -> commentCounts.getOrDefault(post.getId(), 0L) >= count);
}
```